# Reading the maximum size of an expected packet from a C socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a client/server program. The client sends a message to the server and the server processes this message and gets back to the client.

The first four bytes of the client message is the size of the whole message. I also know the maximum size a message can be. However, messages are of variable sizes.

I am using the read function in a while loop to read the client messages

```
while((n = read(socket, buffer, MAX_SIZE)) != 0){
    process_message();
    write(socket, ...);
}
```

I was wondering if there is any harm in reading more bytes than what the client is sending? I can first read the size of the message and then read the exact number of bytes but I was wondering if this is necessary.

Comment: that is one reason that the number of bytes read is returned.  It can only read what is on the socket buffer, and will be unable to return anything more.

Comment: Note that calling read() of N bytes returns *up to* N bytes. It might return fewer and it's your responsibility to accumulate them. Especially important when you read the first 4 bytes which represent the length of the subsequent message as you might not get all 4 bytes in a single read.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the tip about iterative reading until I am sure I received everything. This really solved a bug in my code I have been trying to fix in days.

Comment: @Keeto That's great to hear. Glad that it helped.

Comment: Your loop should be `while ((n = read(...)) > 0)`. It isn't appropriate to keep looping after an error, and using a negative value of `n` inside the loop will cause further failures. You also need to pass `n` to `process_message()`, and use it within the `write()` call. You will also have to remove the implicit assumption that what you received *was* a complete message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in some other comments, reading from a socket can return any number of bytes, up to the maximum requested.

A better loop, although still not without problems, would be something along these lines:

```
/* 4 byte message header that contains the length */
#define MSG_HEADER_SIZE 4
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 128
struct message {
    uint32_t length;
    char body[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
};

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint32_t buf_used = 0;

/* main loop */
while (1) {
    n = recv(socket, buffer + buf_used, sizeof(buffer) - buf_used, 0);

    if (n == -1) {
        /* handle error */
        exit(1);
    }

    if (n == 0) {
        /* connection closed, do something. */
        exit(1);
    }

    buf_used += n;

    /* check for partial/completed message(s) */
    while (buf_used >= MSG_HEADER_SIZE) {
        struct message *cur_msg = (struct message *) buffer;
        uint32_t total_msg_length;

        total_msg_length = cur_msg->length + MSG_HEADER_SIZE;

        /* is this message completed yet? */
        if (buf_used >= total_msg_length) {
            process_message(cur_msg);

            /* remove message since it has been processed */
            buf_used -= total_msg_length;

            /* this could potentially be optimized */
            memmove(buffer, buffer + total_msg_length, buf_used);
        } else {
            /* have incomplete message */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

For an introduction to socket programming, I would recommend checking out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Comment: It isn't 'most likely closed connection', it is *definitely* a closed connection. The peer has either closed his socket or shut it down for output. No other possibilities. In both cases there will never be any more data to read from this socket.

Comment: Yeah, the "most likely" part was, "most likely I am remembering this correctly". Updated the code comment, thanks.